# Different Date.parse results for 2011-11-15 and 2011/11/15

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-parsing

Why `Date.parse("2011-11-15")` considers current time zone in Web browser, and  `Date.parse("2011/11/15")` does not? Why the results are different?

Comment: Take a look at the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first form is being considered as an ISO date in UTC, according to section 15.9.1.15 of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). The second form is being considered in an implementation-specific way, as per section 15.9.4.2:

> The `parse` function applies the `ToString` operator to its argument and interprets the resulting String as a date 
>   and time; it returns a Number, the UTC time value corresponding to the date and time. The String may be 
>   interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the 
>   String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any 
>   implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats

So I suspect "2011/11/15" is being converted to the *local* midnight of November 15th, whereas "2011-11-15" is being converted to *UTC* midnight of November 15th.

Comment: +1.  As that last sentence quoted makes clear, moreover, it is not guaranteed that implementations will parse "2011-11-15" or "2011/11/15" differently, or the same.

Comment: @PeterO.: Indeed. The parsing of "2011-11-15" is guaranteed, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks, Jon! Will consult ECMA specs next time :)

Answer (score 1):

from [date.parse documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. Starting with
>   JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4, a subset of ISO 8601 is supported. For
>   example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date and
>   time) can be passed and parsed. Timezones in ISO dates are not yet
>   supported, so e.g. "2011-10-10T14:48:00+0200" (with timezone) does not
>   give the intended result yet.

Comment: It's worth making it clear that that's the Date.parse documentation *for Firefox*.

Comment: @JonSkeet There is not a single specific website having java-script documentation,So i always take reference from MDC. if you know any good website then please refer me. Thanks :)

Comment: See my answer, which refers to the ECMA-262 specification. But even if that didn't exist, it would be worth being explicit about which variant you *are* using.

Comment: I've seen MDC docs, and it doesn't answer the question - why the difference exists. ECMA is much more specific, thanks!